# Why is LB_GETITEMDATA returning 0?

Tags: c++, winapi, listbox

I'm trying to create a program that suspends and resumes processes, it creates a listbox with text strings of all the running processes on the system, but when I click the suspend button to suspend a process I try to send WM_GETITEMDATA for the currently selected item in the listbox but the value returns 0. I expected the return value to be a string with the text of the lParam of LB_ADDSTRING.

I think this has something to do with the scope of the function I use LB_ADDSTRING in because when I use LB_GETITEMDATA right after LB_ADDSTRING it properly returns the value of the lParam of LB_ADDSTRING. Since I am unsure of where my error lies I'm adding the full source code to the bottom of my question. Here is the function I use to add strings to the listbox:

```
void RefreshList()
{
    SendMessage (hlist, LB_RESETCONTENT, 0, 0);
    HANDLE hSnapShot3 = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPALL, NULL);
    PROCESSENTRY32 pEntry3;
    pEntry3.dwSize = sizeof (pEntry3);
    BOOL hRes3 = Process32First(hSnapShot3, &pEntry3);
    int listitem = 0;
    while (hRes3)
    {

        SendMessage (hlist, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)pEntry3.szExeFile);
        SendMessage (hlist, LB_SETITEMDATA, listitem, (LPARAM)pEntry3.szExeFile);
        SendMessage(hlist, LB_GETITEMDATA, listitem, NULL);
        MessageBox(0,0,0,0);
        listitem++;
        hRes3 = Process32Next(hSnapShot3, &pEntry3);
    }
    CloseHandle(hSnapShot3);
}
```

Here is the part of the windows procedure where I catch clicks to my context menu and try to send the message LB_GETITEMDATA:

```
    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (HIWORD(wParam) == 0 && LOWORD(wParam) == 1)
        {
        selection = SendMessage(hlist, LB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0);
        LRESULT selectionname = SendMessage(hlist, LB_GETITEMDATA, selection, NULL);
        }
```

here is the full code

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500
#include <windows.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <Tlhelp32.h>
#include <winbase.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#define list1 1
#define button1 2
int selection;
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
LRESULT CALLBACK ProcessListProc (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
char szClassName[ ] = "mainwindowclass";
HWND hlist;
HWND hwnd;
void RefreshList()
{
    SendMessage (hlist, LB_RESETCONTENT, 0, 0);
    HANDLE hSnapShot3 = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPALL, NULL);
    PROCESSENTRY32 pEntry3;
    pEntry3.dwSize = sizeof (pEntry3);
    BOOL hRes3 = Process32First(hSnapShot3, &pEntry3);
    int listitem = 0;
    while (hRes3)
    {

        SendMessage (hlist, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)pEntry3.szExeFile);
        SendMessage (hlist, LB_SETITEMDATA, listitem, (LPARAM)pEntry3.szExeFile);
        SendMessage(hlist, LB_GETITEMDATA, listitem, NULL);
        MessageBox(0,0,0,0);
        listitem++;
        hRes3 = Process32Next(hSnapShot3, &pEntry3);
    }
    CloseHandle(hSnapShot3);
}

int SuspendProcess(TCHAR processname)
{
    int doublePID = 0;
    DWORD pidtoacton;
    DWORD Result;
    HANDLE hSnapShot3 = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPALL, NULL);
    PROCESSENTRY32 pEntry3;
    pEntry3.dwSize = sizeof (pEntry3);
    BOOL hRes3 = Process32First(hSnapShot3, &pEntry3);
    while (hRes3)
    {
            if (processname == pEntry3.szExeFile);
            {
                if (doublePID != 0)
                {
                    MessageBox (NULL, "2 processes of the same type detected, support not yet implimented!", NULL, MB_OK);
                }
            pidtoacton = pEntry3.th32ProcessID;
            doublePID++;
            }
    hRes3 = Process32Next(hSnapShot3, &pEntry3);
    }
    HANDLE tsnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot (TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD, 0);
    THREADENTRY32 tentry;
    tentry.dwSize = sizeof (tentry);
    BOOL CRec = Thread32First(tsnap, &tentry);
    while (CRec)
    {
        if (tentry.th32OwnerProcessID == pidtoacton)
     {
         HANDLE handletoacton = OpenThread(2, 0, tentry.th32ThreadID);
         Result = SuspendThread(handletoacton);
         if (Result == -1)
         {
             MessageBox (NULL, "An unknown error has occured when attempting to suspend a thread in the process", NULL, MB_OK);
         }
     }
     CRec = Thread32Next(tsnap, &tentry);
    }
    CloseHandle(tsnap);
}

    MSG messages;
int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hThisInstance,
                    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                    LPSTR lpszArgument,
                    int nCmdShow)
{
          /* Here messages to the application are saved */
    WNDCLASSEX wincl;        /* Data structure for the windowclass */
    MSG messages2;

    /* The Window structure */
    wincl.hInstance = hThisInstance;
    wincl.lpszClassName = szClassName;
    wincl.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;      /* This function is called by windows */
    wincl.style = CS_DBLCLKS;                 /* Catch double-clicks */
    wincl.cbSize = sizeof (WNDCLASSEX);

    /* Use default icon and mouse-pointer */
    wincl.hIcon = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wincl.hIconSm = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wincl.hCursor = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wincl.lpszMenuName = NULL;                 /* No menu */
    wincl.cbClsExtra = 0;                      /* No extra bytes after the window class */
    wincl.cbWndExtra = 0;                      /* structure or the window instance */
    /* Use Windows's default colour as the background of the window */
    wincl.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) COLOR_BACKGROUND;

    /* Register the window class, and if it fails quit the program */
    if (!RegisterClassEx (&wincl))
        return 0;
    /* Register the window class, and if it fails quit the program */

    /* The class is registered, let's create the program*/
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx (
               0,                   /* Extended possibilites for variation */
               szClassName,         /* Classname */
               "Process suspender",       /* Title Text */
               WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, /* default window */
               CW_USEDEFAULT,       /* Windows decides the position */
               CW_USEDEFAULT,       /* where the window ends up on the screen */
               350,                 /* The programs width */
               650,                 /* and height in pixels */
               HWND_DESKTOP,        /* The window is a child-window to desktop */
               NULL,                /* No menu */
               hThisInstance,       /* Program Instance handler */
               NULL                 /* No Window Creation data */
           );

    hlist = CreateWindowEx (0,TEXT("listbox"),NULL,WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|LBS_NOTIFY|LBS_STANDARD|LBS_HASSTRINGS,10,15,320,500,hwnd,(HMENU)list1,NULL,NULL);
    RefreshList();

    HWND hWndButton = CreateWindowEx(NULL,
                                     TEXT("button"),
                                     TEXT("refresh"),
                                     WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,
                                     130,
                                     535,
                                     80,
                                     30,
                                     hwnd,
                                     (HMENU)button1,
                                     NULL,
                                     NULL);

    /* Make the window visible on the screen */
    ShowWindow (hwnd, nCmdShow);

    /* Run the message loop. It will run until GetMessage() returns 0 */
    while (GetMessage (&messages, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        /* Translate virtual-key messages into character messages */
        TranslateMessage(&messages);
        /* Send message to WindowProcedure */
        DispatchMessage(&messages);
    }

    /* The program return-value is 0 - The value that PostQuitMessage() gave */
    return messages.wParam;
}


/*  This function is called by the Windows function DispatchMessage()  */

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)                  /* handle the messages */
    {
    case WM_CONTEXTMENU:
    {
        if ((HWND)wParam == hlist)
        {
         INPUT clickin;
         clickin.type = 0;
         clickin.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;
         clickin.mi.dx = 0;
         clickin.mi.dy = 0;
         clickin.mi.mouseData = 0;
         clickin.mi.time = 0;
         clickin.mi.dwExtraInfo = 0;
         SendInput(1,&clickin,sizeof(clickin));
         clickin.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;
         SendInput(1,&clickin,sizeof(clickin));
         GetMessage (&messages, NULL, 0, 0);
         TranslateMessage(&messages);
         DispatchMessage(&messages);
         int xPos = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
         int yPos = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);
         HMENU rightclickmenu = CreatePopupMenu();
         InsertMenu(rightclickmenu, 1, MF_BYCOMMAND | MF_STRING | MF_ENABLED, 1, "Suspend");
         InsertMenu(rightclickmenu, 0, MF_BYCOMMAND | MF_STRING | MF_ENABLED, 0, "Resume");
         TrackPopupMenu(rightclickmenu, TPM_TOPALIGN | TPM_LEFTALIGN, xPos, yPos, 0, hwnd, NULL);
        }
        break;
    }
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage (0);       /* send a WM_QUIT to the message queue */
        break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (HIWORD(wParam) == 0 && LOWORD(wParam) == 1)
        {
        selection = SendMessage(hlist, LB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0);
        LRESULT selectionname = SendMessage(hlist, LB_GETITEMDATA, selection, NULL);
        }
        switch (wParam)
        {
        case button1:
            RefreshList();
            break;
        }
    default:
        return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `LB_GETTEXT` to get the text for a listbox item, not `LB_GETITEMDATA`.

Comment: You are just storing a pointer.  What it points to is long gone, overwritten by Process32Next().  And destroyed by CloseHandle(hSnapShot3).  You'll need to copy pEntry3.szExeFile to the heap to keep it valid.  Don't forget to clean up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @JonathanPotter mentions in his comment, you need to use [LB_GETTEXT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761313(v=vs.85).aspx) to retrieve the text of an item.

If you were going to use `LB_SETITEMDATA` to store, say, the process-id for each item, it is good practice to always use the index returned by the `LB_ADDSTRING` and not assume that the index will always increment by one, this will work for sorted and unsorted list boxes:

```
listitem = SendMessage(hlist, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)pEntry3.szExeFile);
SendMessage(hlist, LB_SETITEMDATA, listitem, (LPARAM)pEntry3.th32ProcessID);
```